# Querying and displaying from a database using Sessions

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to query from a phpmyadmin database, comparing an email with a session that was collected during the login.I want to echo it out on a profile page

This is the code for profile.php:

```
 $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

session_start();

$sql = "SELECT Email, First_Name, Last_Name FROM Users WHERE Email='$Email_Ses'";


 if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
// output data of each row
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo "email: " . $row["Email"]. " - Name: " . $row["First_Name"]. " " . 
 $row["Last_Name"]. "<br>";
 }
} else {
echo "0 results";
}
```

This is the code for the Login:

```
      session_start();        

      if(isset($_POST['email']))

    {
        $_SESSION['Email_Ses'] = $_POST ['email'];
       $_SESSION['Name_Ses'] = $_POST ['name'];
        $password =$_POST ['password'];

        $Email_Ses = $_SESSION['Email_Ses'];

        $Name_Ses =   $_SESSION['Name_Ses'];

        $query = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Email='$Email_Ses' AND Password='$password' LIMIT 1";
```

I want to echo out the logged in users's details on a profile page

But i get this error

```
Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null 
given in /home/ubuntu/workspace/profile.php on line 20
```

the error is on this line:

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
```

Comment: are you sure the above code is not a copy/paste error?? `$sql = "SELECT Email, First_Name, Last_Name FROM Users WHERE Email= 
=$sql = "SELECT Email, First_Name, Last_Name FROM Users WHERE Email= 
='$Email_Ses'";`

Comment: It looks like your `$result` variable doesn't exist. Try adding `$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);` above the `mysqli_num_rows($result)`-call.

Comment: The first snippet of sql and php - the sql is not executed and your code is vulnerable to sql injection

Comment: On a side note, consider switching to PDO instead of mysqli because, as @RamRaider stated, mysqli has some security issues that only partially can be secured by sanitizing input

Comment: Don't store user's password's in plain text.. ( http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php )

Answer (score 0):

If you were to use prepared statements you could avoid nasty surprises due to sql injection.

```
<?php

    /* profile.php*/
    session_start();

    $conn = mysqli_connect( $servername, $username, $password, $dbname );

    $sql = "select `email`, `first_name`, `last_name` from `users` where `email`=?";
    $stmt=$conn->prepare( $sql );

    if( $stmt && isset( $_SESSION['Email_Ses'] ) ){

        $stmt->bind_param('s', $_SESSION['Email_Ses'] );
        $result=$stmt->execute();

        if( $result ){
            $stmt->store_result();
            $stmt->bind_result( $email, $firstname, $lastname );
            $stmt->fetch();
            $stmt->free_result();
            $stmt->close();

            echo "email: $email, Name: $firstname $lastname";
        } else {
            echo "No results"
        }
    }
?>
```

The `login` script is - or should be a little different. Generally the accepted way of storing a user's password is to do so in a hashed format within the database - but this depends upon the version of PHP that you have - I think 5.6+ has `password_hash` and `password_verify` natively - before that there is a 3rd party script to achieve the same thing. I'd strongly suggest that the user's password is hashed!

```
<?php
    /* login.php */
    session_start();        

    if( isset( $_POST['email'],$_POST['name'],$_POST['password'] ) ){

        $email=$_POST['email'];
        $name=$_POST['name'];
        $password=$_POST['password'];

        $sql='select `password` from `users` where `email`=?';
        $stmt=$conn->prepare( $sql );
        if( $stmt ){
            $stmt->bind_param('s',$email);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->store_result();
            $stmt->bind_result( $dbpwd );
            $stmt->fetch();
            $stmt->free_result();
            $stmt->close();

            /* 
                here is where, if the password was hashed, you would use `password_verify` 
                but in this case it is not.
            */

            if( $dbpwd==$password ){
                /* ok */

                $_SESSION['Email_Ses'] = $email;
                $_SESSION['Name_Ses'] = $name;

            } else {
                /* bogus */
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

For the record - this is not tested but should help get started using prepared statements. For more info regarding the password functions mentioned above try [password_hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [password_verify](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php)

Answer (score -1):

your $result variable does't exist.

```
$sql = mysqli_query("SELECT Email, First_Name, Last_Name FROM Users WHERE Email= ='$Email_Ses'");
$result = mysqli_num_rows($conn,$sql);
if ($result > 0) 
{
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
    {
        echo "email: " . $row["Email"]. " - Name: " . $row["First_Name"]. " " . 
        $row["Last_Name"]. "<br>";
    }
} 
else 
{
    echo "0 results";
}
```

Comment: Tried that, it didn't work got this error   mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given

Comment: I have doing some changes in my code. try again @Adam and let me know